# fwrite: unexpected t_string (php)

Tags: php, fwrite

So I currently have (*functions.php*)

```
1 function onlineplayers() {
2   $fp = fsockopen('12.34.56.78', 12345, $errno, $errstr, 4);
3    fwrite($fp, '\xFE');
4    $answer = fread($fp, 256);
5    ...
6 }
```

to ping a webserver and embedded with

```
1 <?php require("functions.php"); ?>
```

but running the site gives

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ' ' (T_STRING) in functions.php on line 3

But what is the problem? I tried just to do **fwrite("a", "a");** but it won't work.

Comment: Your `onlineplayers()` function's code does not give me any syntax errors on `PHP 7.1`.

Comment: Note that escape sequences aren't expanded in single quotes. If you want `\xFE` to be a hex character you need to use double quotes.

Comment: Are you sure that's the line it's complaining about? `functions.php` needs to begin with `<?php`. If it does, then line 3 will be the line beginning with `$fp =`.

Comment: Anyway, often syntax errors like this are due to a problem on the previous line, like a missing quote or semicolon.

Comment: try:  fwrite($fp, "\xFE");

Comment: @halojoy That will solve the escape problem I mentioned, it won't fixed the "unexpected T_STRING" error.

Comment: → Invisible stray Unicode

Comment: I am still getting the syntax error with "\xFF" and its definitely in that line. Btw I have PHP v7.2.0 .